# Android: multiline text in menu item

Tags: android, menu, multilinestring

I need to dynamically put information about a user (name + email), to the first item of my menu. The information should be displayed on two lines within the first menu item.
I have already tried:

```
android:lines="2"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLines="4"
android:singleLine="false"
```

and:

```
System.getProperty ("line.separator")
\n, \r
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
(Html.fromHtml("text before break<br/>text after break").toString());
```

but there is no effect. Will greatly appreciate any help or hint!

Comment: Have you tried `android:text="First line\nSecond line"`?

Comment: @Cheticamp, yes I have, but also with no result.